# Truncate text in AspxGridView cells

Tags: devexpress, truncate, aspxgridview

Is there a way to truncate long text in AspxGridView cells?

I've read and implemented this solution. , http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic

...which of course works BUT only for one column and I need to create this with several columns.

Here is my solution so far

```
protected void AsPxGridView1CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName != "AnalysisFeedbackAuto") return;
    if (e.Value.ToString().Length > 13)
    {
        var displayText = Regex.Replace(e.Value.ToString(), "<.*?>", string.Empty).Substring(0, 10);
        e.DisplayText = string.Concat(displayText, "...");
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Thanks

=== UPDATE ===
Obviously this was the solution

```
protected void AsPxGridView1CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "AnalysisFeedbackAuto" 
        || e.Column.FieldName == "AnalysisResults"
        || e.Column.FieldName == "AnalysisAnswers"
        )
    {
        if (e.Value.ToString().Length > 13)
        {
            var displayText = Regex.Replace(e.Value.ToString(), "<.*?>", string.Empty).Substring(0, 10);
            e.DisplayText = string.Concat(displayText, "...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Width can be fixed and CSS Ellipses can be used... works well in a modern browser, but it will still transfer the "extra data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void AsPxGridView1CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "AnalysisFeedbackAuto" 
        || e.Column.FieldName == "AnalysisResults"
        || e.Column.FieldName == "AnalysisAnswers"
        )
    {
        if (e.Value.ToString().Length > 13)
        {
            var displayText = Regex.Replace(e.Value.ToString(), "<.*?>", string.Empty).Substring(0, 10);
            e.DisplayText = string.Concat(displayText, "...");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are solutions from DevExpress:

http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q300507

http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q303093